# ERROR/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Gurgaon:

Tags: android

i want display location name according city name selected from database but it gives error no such column gurgaon i save my sqlite manager data base in assets folder....
so how to run nested query in sqlite and how to store query result in a variable in android sqlite....thanks

```
package cabs.h;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.R.string;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
   //The Android's default system path of your application database.
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/cabs.h/databases/";
 private static String DB_NAME = "CabBookingDatabase.sqlite";
 private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
 private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}  

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

   boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

   if (dbExist) {
       Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");
       // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
       // writeable database, but only if the version number has been
       // bumped
       this.getWritableDatabase();
       }
       dbExist = checkDataBase();
       if (!dbExist) {
       // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
       // the default system path of your application so we are gonna be
       // able to overwrite that database with our database.
       this.getReadableDatabase();

       try {

         copyDataBase();

      } catch (IOException e) {

          throw new Error("Error copying database");

       }
   }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

   SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

   try{
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
      checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

   }catch(SQLiteException e)
   {

      //database does't exist yet.

   }

   if(checkDB != null){

      checkDB.close();

   }

   return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{

   //Open your local db as the input stream
   InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

   // Path to the just created empty db
   String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

   //Open the empty db as the output stream
   OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

   //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int length;
   while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
      myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }

   //Close the streams
   myOutput.flush();
   myOutput.close();
   myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

   //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
   myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

       if(myDataBase != null)
          myDataBase.close();

       super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w("tag", "Upgrading database from version which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS liberQuoti");
    onCreate(db);

}

public Cursor getcity()
{
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 Cursor cur ;
 cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("select cityName from CityType", null);
 int citynameIndex = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cityName");
//String valuecity = cur.getString(citynameIndex);
//Log.d("No.of tweets,,,,,,,", valuecity );

 cur.moveToFirst();
//Log.d("No.of tweets,,,,,,,", +accountnameIndex + "tgr" );
myDataBase.close();


return cur; 
}
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
public Cursor getloc()
{
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 Cursor cur1,cur2;
 String saa = cabbookingapplication.Selection;
 String sql="select CityType.rowid from CityType where CityType.cityName="+saa+"";
//  int sql=2;
 cur1 = myDataBase.rawQuery("select locationName from Location where cityId=("+sql+")", null);
 cur1.moveToFirst();
 myDataBase.close();
return cur1; 
}
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 public Cursor getservice()
{
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 Cursor cur3;
 cur3 = myDataBase.rawQuery("select serviceType from ServiceType", null);
 cur3.moveToFirst();
 myDataBase.close();
return cur3; 
}
public Cursor getcabtype()
{
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 Cursor cur4;
 cur4 = myDataBase.rawQuery("select carType from CarType", null);
 cur4.moveToFirst();
 myDataBase.close();
return cur4; 
}
public Cursor getcabservice()
{
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 Cursor cur5;
 cur5 = myDataBase.rawQuery("select cabFeatures from CabFeatures", null);
 cur5.moveToFirst();
 myDataBase.close();
return cur5; 
}
public Cursor getday()
{
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 Cursor cur6;
 cur6 = myDataBase.rawQuery("select dayTravell from DayTravell", null);
 cur6.moveToFirst();
 myDataBase.close();
return cur6; 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're closing your database when returning cursors -- thus the cursor will point to a closed database which means you can't use it (you might be able to use the first record since you moved to that before closing it). Not to mention opening/closing takes up some time. You should just open the DB once in `onCreate` and then close it once in `onDestroy`.
2. Android only supports a single SQL statement in `rawQuery`, so what you want cannot be achieved by nesting SQL statements

Try something like:

```
String sql = "SELECT CityType.rowid, Location.locationName FROM Location, CityType " +
    "WHERE Location.cityId = CityType.rowid " +
    "AND CityType.cityName = " + saa;
```

Also please post the error output from LogCat.

Change your DatabaseHelper to something like the following (notice I'm not opening the database for each query - you need to make sure to call the `open` and `close` methods in the `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods of your Activity).

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ...

    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    // change openDatabase to this:
    // call it ONCE in onCreate of your activity
    public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {
        if (mDb != null)
            return; // already opened
        mDb = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return mDb;
    }
    // call this in the onDestroy of your activity
    public void close() {
        if (mDb == null)
            return; // db is not open
        mDb.close();
        mDb = null;
    }


    // Change getLoc and your other methods to be something like this
    public Cursor getLocation() {
        if (mDb == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Database has not been opened by activity");

        String saa = cabbookingapplication.Selection;
        String sql = "SELECT CityType.rowid, Location.locationName FROM Location, CityType " +
    "WHERE Location.cityId = CityType.rowid " +
    "AND CityType.cityName = " + saa;
        return mDb.rawQuery(sql);
    }
    ...
}
```

Also

- Make sure to call `startManagingCursor` on any cursors you don't close pretty much straight away to avoid memory leaks (i.e. cursors you use in adapters should be managed)
- I haven't called `Cursor.moveToFirst()` in my above example, so call that if you want.

I usually call it outside of my adapter to so I can do something like

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    // we have at least 1 record
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // do something with current row
    }
} else {
   // no rows, show an empty message or something
}
```

Comment: @ joseph
/data/data/cabs.h/databases/CabBookingDatabase.sqlite SQLiteDatabase created and never closed

Comment: earl  hi...it works but problem is in place of "saa" variable "null" is coming

Comment: Added code at the bottom of my post to explain using an adapter and not opening the database every time. `saa` comes from `cabbookingapplication.Selection` so `Selection` must be null - I don't have to the code for your booking app so I can't say why that is null.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on htc desire hd. For more info check here http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IN` instead of `=`:

```
String sql = "select CityType.rowid from CityType where CityType.cityName = "
    + saa;
cur1 = myDataBase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT locationName FROM Location WHERE cityId in (" + sql + ")", null);
```

Or simply a join:

```
String sql = "SELECT locationName FROM Location, CityType " +
    "where cityId = CityType.rowid " +
    "AND CityType.cityName = " + saa;
```

Apparently on some devices you may also have to close the database you open with `getReadableDatabase`:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
db.close();
```

Comment: public Cursor getloc()
   {
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
     Cursor cur1,cur2;
     String saa = cabbookingapplication.Selection;
     String sql = "SELECT locationName FROM Location, CityType " +
     "where cityId = CityType.rowid " +
     "AND CityType.cityName = " + saa;
   //  int sql=2;

     cur1 = myDataBase.rawQuery(
          sql, null);
     cur1.moveToFirst();
     myDataBase.close();
   return cur1; 
   }

Comment: not works for me locaion is not shown in spinner and giving same error

Comment: Did you try the last suggestion?

Comment: when i selected the city from spinner via database save on assets folder i want show the locatoin name resides on that city..but it is blank.....whats the reason  i try help but not work

Comment: @matthew willis ....ya...it works but "null" is coming in place of "saa" variable ie. data comes from other class